# String concatenation in resource file

Tags: c++, boost, mfc, token, preprocessor

It looks like compiler can't concatenate strings in resource file:
for example:

```
STRINGTABLE 
BEGIN 
CTEXT "App Name: " "Notepad Super" " Viewer "
```

I want "App Name: " and " Viewer " to be constant literals. And main name "Notepad" to be macro define.
Compiler can't do it for rc file so I want to use preprocessor:

```
#define NAME_RC Notepad Super
CTEXT BOOST_PP_STRINGIZE(BOOST_PP_CAT(App Name: , BOOST_PP_CAT(NAME_RC, Viewer)))
```

And this way I obtain:
**App Name:Notepad SuperViewer**

However macro takes only tokens and trims all leading or trailing whitespaces. How can i fix it? I want to have:
**App Name: Notepad Super Viewer**

Best regards

Comment: This is a possible duplicate to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35057803/concatenate-string-and-constant-in-resource-file-in-c-mfc

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Concatenate string and constant in resource file in C++ (MFC)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35057803/concatenate-string-and-constant-in-resource-file-in-c-mfc)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12637325/concate-define-and-string-in-resources/12648021#12648021

Comment: Thank you Christopher,
That solved my problem