# Concatenate String in resource file and pass it to menu item string (winapi) c++

Tags: c++, winapi, menuitem, string-concatenation, resource-files

I am writing a win32 application using winapi
and i want to concatenate a string in my resource file and give the stirng to my menuitem as the string it should show. 
when i want to give it to a control it works like a charm, but when i want to 
use it for the menuItem i get an error message. this might me because the preprocessor does not see the concatination as a string?

does anybody have a clue or idea what i could try? 
there were simillar post i tried to follow - but it gives me the same result...

other posts on so:

[Concatenate string and constant in resource file in C++ (MFC)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35057803/concatenate-string-and-constant-in-resource-file-in-c-mfc)

[Concate define and string in resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12637325/concate-define-and-string-in-resources)

[C/C++ Macro string concatenation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5256313/c-c-macro-string-concatenation)

as i followed these answeres, i got "ID_ABOUT_STR" as my output instead of the value of it most of the times... and else i got the error...

i hope the question is clear and thank you in advance for the effort :)

.rc File:

```
IDR_MENU1 MENU
BEGIN
    POPUP L"System"
    BEGIN
        MENUITEM ID_EXIT_STR, ID_SYSTEM_EXIT
        MENUITEM SEPARATOR
        MENUITEM ID_ABOUT_STR, ID_SYSTEM_ABOUT //here i want to give it the ID_ABOUT_STR which is in the resource file... 
    END
END
```

resource.h : VER_PRODUCTNAME_STR and the other one just contain strings aswell

```
#define ID_ABOUT_STR                 L"About" VER_PRODUCTNAME_STR L" " VER_FILE_DESCRIPTION_STR
```

This is the error i get:

```
Error       RC2122  unknown menu subtype                PRO-PRODUCITON      C:\XXX.rc       195 
Error       RC2125  expected ID value for menu item     PRO-PRODUCITON      C:\XXX.rc       195
```

Comment: The RC compiler has similarities to the C pre-processor but it does not use it; it has own rules and IIRC it does not do string concatenation.  See comments to: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20171004-00/?p=97126 for possible workarounds

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the L extension from my point of view. The code should compile without the L"..." prefix.

And as your links show, this macros work without problems in the RC compiler

```
#define CONCAT(a,b) a##b
#define STRINGIZE_(x) #x
#define STRINGIZE(x) STRINGIZE_(x)
```

As a sample this works for a caption in a dialog

```
CAPTION STRINGIZE(CONCAT(Concat,Title))
```

But they don't use the L"..." prefix

Comment: i have tried it without the L prefix together with the stringize and concat - which gives me the error :
RC2104 undefined keyword or key name: about\ 

The wierd thing really is, that on other controls i use in the rc file it works even withouth the usage of concat. Only the menu item seems to have a problem with it.